# Joomla save, save and close, save and new, save as copy buttons not work

Tags: joomla

I update a joomla 1.5 site to jommla 2.5.9. I make a sub directory under the public_html and do all upgrading process there. In that directory save, save and close, save and new, save as copy button work correctly. But when I transfer this to public_html these buttons not work. I also try akeeba backup method but result same.
Can anyone tell me where is the problem.

Comment: edit your configuration.php manually and make sure all paths are correct. Also if you could post the error (javascript or server-side?) that would help

Answer (score 0):

Use Akeeba "backup" and "kickstart" to back up and mover your 1.5 site first. Then update from the new location.

https://www.akeebabackup.com/products.html - developer link
https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606 - Joomla extention link.

I NEVER build a Joomla X.X site without FIRST installing Akeeba, it the BEST component for backing up, moving and restoring sites.

Good luck!